# How does break enchantment work on stone shaped wall?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic

If the spell [*stone shape*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/stone-shape) is used to create an opening in a stone wall, what happens when the spell [*break enchantment*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/break-enchantment) is used against the *stone shape* effect? Would the wall become as it was before it was shaped by the spell?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nothing happens because a wall or door is not a valid target for Break Enchantment. The target for Break Enchantment is *"up to one creature per level, all within 30 ft. of each other"*, doors and walls are not creatures so they can't be targeted by Break Enchantment.

Comment: Good point, I had missed that in the description and paid far more attention to the first line, missing the information there too.

Comment: Nothing would happen if a Dispel Magic was cast either, because the duration of Stone Shape is instantaneous.

Comment: @ShadowKras - Note that "*Break Enchantment can reverse even an instantaneous effect.*" - so it would've worked if the target was valid...